# Java Properties file to JSON

Tags: javascript, java, json

I am looking to convert a properties file to JSON.

An idea I had was to somehow convert everything in my properties into an object, and then parse it to JSON somehow.

```
{
    admin: Admin
    advisor: Advisor{0}
    advisor2: Advisor
    additional_inspections: Additional Inspections
}
```

So I swapped the '=' for ':', but now I need everything on the right hand side of the colon into a string so that I can parse it. Is there an easier way to turn my .properties file into JSON?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/properties

Comment: Are you looking for a solution using Java or JavaScript?

Comment: @slartidan preferably Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a parser for it? It should take a few lines. Meanwhile check out [typesafe config HOCON](https://github.com/typesafehub/config).